# Como enviar un array desde un select a una base de datos

Tags: php, postgresql-12

En este select estoy trayendo ciertos datos de mi DB, y con en `name="select[]"` envio al controlador los datos multiples que haya seleccionado

```
    <div>
    <select class="select-limit" multiple id="select" name="select[]">                                                                            
            <?php
                $listar = ConsultaModel::mdlMostrarCasos();
                foreach ($listar as $k => $value) {
                    $codigo = $value->codigo_db;
                    $nombre = $value->nombre_db;
            ?>
                <optgroup>
                <option value="<?php echo $codigo; ?>"><?php echo $nombre; ?>
                </option>
                </optgroup>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

En mi controlador los recibo de manera correctamente, para mi!

```
    <?php 
    static public function crearUnCaso()
    {
        if (isset($_POST["select"])) {
            $caso=  $_POST["select"];
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($caso); $i++) {

                $json = $caso[$i];
                print_r(' ' . $json);
            }
        $respuesta = registrModel::mdlCrearRegistro($json);
        print_r($respuesta);
        }
    }
?>
```

Cual es mi necesidad, tomar estos datos que estan en la variable $json y poder guardarlos en otra DB

Esto es lo que tengo en mi modelo

```
static public function mdlCrearNuevosDatos($json) { 
    try { 
        //code...
        $sql = "INSERT INTO mi_tabla ($json) VALUES (:mi_columna)"; 
        $sql = Conexion::conectar()->prepare($sql); 
        $sql->bindParam(':json', $json, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25); 
        $sql->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) { 
        return $e; 
    }
}
```

Cabe mencionar que si escojo 4 valores del select, solamente envia el ultimo dato

Comment: ¿porque $respuesta queda fuera del bucle for? ¿que es :mi_columna (no la defines)?  ¿donde aplicas el parámetro :json en tu consulta? ¿porque usas $json en ella directamente? ¿porque pones name="select[]" en lugar de name="select" si ya es un array al declararlo multiple? Creo que si resuelves esas cuestiones lo resolverás por ti mismo

Comment: falta algo muy importante; la variable $json es un array en realidad en ningun mommento lo conviertes en un array string.... la base dedatos no pueden recibir ese tipo de dato array que le envias ... primero debes convertirlo en un string tipo json...

Comment: oye muchas gracias, no mire que la $respuesta estaba fuera del for

Comment: al colocar esto name="select[] ya lo esta convirtiendo

Comment: no ... eso es html eso permite enviar un array a php mediante post... al recibirlo en php sigue siendo un array ... las base de datos no guardan array en formato array... necesitos convertirlo en json